# Can Netty process a single pipeline with multiple threads?

Tags: concurrency, netty, pipelining

I have a Netty 4 application that is receiving messages at high throughput using a single network connection (or to be precise, a single IP multicast group), so processing of all channel handlers in the pipeline is basically single-threaded.

Is there a way to configure Netty to parallelize processing so that more than 1 core gets used? I'm thinking of the "pipelining pattern" of multi-threading aka [synchronous concurrency](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Synchronous_concurrency). Is something like that built-in - or would I have to implement this myself, off the Netty pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can add different handlers with different `EventLoopGroup`s to the pipeline. This way you can offload to different threads. That said you may need to be careful in terms of ordering (depending on the protocol)

Comment: Thanks Norman. Not sure about your heads-up regarding ordering. Are you saying that messages could come out in a different order at the end of the pipeline? In that case, I guess I just `new NioEventLoopGroup(1)` for every handler. As I only have one "connection", it should not hurt me performance-wise, but it would make sure that items cannot overtake another, right? (But I don't know if `NioEventLoopGroup` is the right implementation for channel-specific `EventLoopGroup`s...)

Comment: Perhaps some descendant of `SingleThreadEventLoop` would be better - is there an example somewhere of handler-specific event loop groups that I can refer to?